# Why are most social networking sites in blue?

Tags: website-design, color, color-scheme

Why do most social media websites use blue as the main color? e.g., Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn, foursquare, ...

I am only interested in answers based on some scientific research.

Comment: Perhaps, it has to do with a distinctive theme for social media sites. [Not an 'answer', as it's not based on research.]

Comment: Facebook is blue because Mark Zukerberg is red-green colorblind. Facebooks blue color design inspired other social sites?

Comment: Windows Xps desktop picture had a lot of blue: some grass and lots of blue sky

Comment: Blue has been prevalent in design since before facebook. Blue's a great color for the great majority of colorblind users too, since it lets you pick a secondary color that's almost certainly readable to red green colorblind users.

Comment: see also http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20583/why-are-primary-call-to-action-buttons-usually-plain-blue

Comment: MySpace was blue before all these sites were.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Searching on the web for this I came up with [this article](http://www.aliciacowan.com/guest-posts/social-media-giants-branding).

Quoting from an "Applied Colour Psychology Specialist":

Colour Psychology
Blue is the colour of the intellect, the mind, making it the colour of communication and when you think about social media, it’s all about communicating.

Blue also has the perception as being trustworthy, dependable, safe and reliable.  These are the perceived positive qualities of a business who chooses blue.

World’s Favourite Colour
Research has also shown blue to be the world’s most popular colour.

... read more at the link

Hope this helps

Comment: @AlanHo also, Leon: Think the social networking site designers considered these aspects when deciding on the theme? Any references/ interesting stories?

Comment: yes, color is one of the most important factors when designing an interface, as it conveyes the overall "mood feeling" of the design. Can't find any references now, I'll have to dig up more "scientific research", but I hope my link above is already helping in that direction

Comment: thanks again. I am not expecting some digging up, though. Rather, if anyone happens to have gone through this exercise of evaluating color schemes.

Comment: Blue is an extremely safe color (if you're not using red too!) I was about to post some data about blue being the "most favorite"/popular color as well.

Comment: glad this helped! Pls mark as Answer for the other members... 10x

Answer (score 3):

My own research is based on examination of the world around me...

[image]

...well - that's not quite how it looks out my window - but that would be lovely.

And that's my point - you only have to look to the skies for the colour blue which is why blue is associated with clarity, optimism, heights, hope, wonder, and  [calmness](http://seattletimes.nwsource.com/html/nationworld/2008494010_bluelight11.html).

Blue has been shown in [placebo drug trials](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2359128/pdf/bmj00573-0060.pdf) to be a depressant rather than a stimulant. I can well believe that the calming affect of blue combined with the above characteristics related to the 'sky' effect would result in users having a greater desire to settle in a calm place and therefore staying longer on such a web page rather than the itching-to-move-on that might come with more stimulating colours.

In the above research *(British Medical Journal 313 Dec 1996)*:

> In a single blind experiment showing the effect of placebo Blackwell
>   et al asked 100 medical students to participate in an experiment in
>   which they they would receive either a sedative or stimulant drug."
>   All of the 56 students who volunteered in fact received either a blue
>   or a pink placebo. Subjects taking the blue placebos felt less alert
>   (66%) than those taking the pink (26%) and also more drowsy (72% v 37%
>   respectively).

Comment: sorry but where is the "scientific research" in your answer? As much as I'd like that view from my window (or rather swim in it :), it doesn't really answer the OP's question

Comment: @RogerAttrill: "...clarity, optimism, heights, hope, wonder, and calmness." Yes, but how is that associated with only the Social Networking sites?

Comment: It's not associated only with social networking sites - it doesn't have to be. I believe a need to find connection that relates blue only to social networking sites is a red herring (not a blue herring). Blue is seemingly a good colour for *any* site that might require users to stick around (and can provide the added interest to make that happen). A handful of the top social networking sites just happen to be a very good fit to the theory, but for each popular blue social network, I'm sure you can find another that is *not* predominantly blue.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it is due to:

  1. Readability

  2. Simultaneous contrast of colors

  3. Allowing access to the color-blind: The audience of social networking sites would reach out to people far and wide.

Black-on-White has high readability and so does Blue-on-White ([Abysoft](http://www.ambysoft.com/essays/userInterfaceDesign.html) and [Colors on the Web](http://www.colorsontheweb.com/colorcontrasts.asp)).

 Perhaps, Black-on-White gives people a monochrome impression. Therefore, Blue-on-White themes are more used instead. Other reasons, I guess, are the [perception of blue](http://desktoppub.about.com/cs/colorselection/p/blue.htm) in the societal and cultural context.

For details on color blindness, please see [colorvisiontesting.com](http://colorvisiontesting.com/color2.htm) for article.

Comment: Funny how nothing from that seems to be mentioned in the link below - and I can see why - color contrast and readability are not such big issues anymore (with nowadays high-quality monitors), and color-blindness affects [only about 8.5% of the population](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness) - and btw BLUE is the worst color for color-blinds - so I doubt that's the reason... ;-)

Comment: @Leon Well, what I mean by color contrast is really geared towards the harmony of colors. (Assuming the background is white and text in black). Same thing for color-blinds, it's more of blue (which may look gray) on white versus other analogous colors which may turn out different shades of gray.